# How do I toggle comments with German keyboard?

Tags: sublime-text-3

Sublime text uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to toggle comments. However, when I press that combination with a [German keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout) (where `/` is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>), nothing happens. Selecting `Toggle Comment` in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> works fine, and shows Ctrl+/ as the shortcut.

The shortcut does work fine when switching to English keyboard layout and I press the keys labelled <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>.

Comment: Can't you just use the `/` from the numeric block, i'm doing the same with other IDEs?

Comment: @martinstoeckli I'm using a laptop keyboard, so no numeric block (not even with `Fn`).

Comment: The shortcut maps in the german keyboard to `ctrl+#`.

Comment: @r-stein Thanks for the note, but it doesn't work for me by default, and I see no line in the default config that would have that effect. Did you maybe reconfigure something?

Comment: @phihag if you open the ST console `View >>> Show Console` and write `sublime.log_input(True)` it logs the input events. The input event when pressing`ctrl+#` should be `control+/`.

Comment: @rstein No, it shows up as `control+#`. May be platform-specific? This is on debian sid.

Comment: @phihag Okay it seems to be platform specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default Sublime Text 3 binding seems to detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> with a German keyboard layout as just that, so you need to add an additional shortcut. Click `Preferences` -> `Key Bindings - User` and insert the following line in the JSON array:

```
{"keys": ["ctrl+shift+7"], "command": "toggle_comment", "args": {"block": true}}
```